# How to process and verify integrity a continuous stream of data in Firebase

Tags: firebase

Continuous stream of objects is saved in the Firebase.
They are HTTP traffic representation so they are ordered and paired from business perspective.

Each object has unique timestamp, should it be used as a key?
How to query/monitor such path for newly created documents to be process?

How to efficiently process and verify data integrity:

- That the responses and requests are one after another
- Verify that responses saved after requests really belongs to that request (there are business rules that predict response content)
- How processed documents should(?) be marked to does not slow down process that waits for documents to process.
- When request/response pair is verified is should be put together in a new object. How to save it in a non blocking way?
- When response does not arrive until timeout a new half-filled object should be created and saved. How to monitor if a matching request arrives to update it?

How Firebase should be configured: indexes, paths (other?) to make processing efficient?

Comment: While this is an interesting question, it's far to broad to provide an accurate answer. How Firebase is configured is partially driven by what you want to get out of it, data relationships, and how data is presented to the user. I would suggest adding a platform tag, provide a detailed but brief use case and what you have tried. It doesn't sound like you've written in code in Firebase yet (hence the question about to observe paths for newly added documents). If you go through the Firebase getting started guide and write some test code you may answer your own question.

Comment: Thanks Jay for input. I understand now i have to go back to drawing board to break down problem to smaller chunks.